# Data Movement on Julia (Parallel)

Tags: parallel-processing, julia

We have a function in count_heads.jl:

```
function count_hands(n)
    c::Int=0
    for i=1:n
        c+=rand(Bool)
    end
    c
end
```

we run julia as `./julia -p 2` 
we want to calculate `a` and `b` in different process and we have :

```
julia> @everywhere include("count_hands.jl")
julia> a=@spawn count_hands(1000000000)
julia> b=@spawn count_hands(1000000000)
julia> fetch(a)+fetch(b)
```

1: How we can be sure we are calculating `a` and `b` in a different process? 
I know we can use `@spawnat` instead of `@spawn` and choose the number of process but I saw this code and I want to know How we can sure about that.

we suppose it is correct and both of them are computing in different process, `count_hands(1000000000)` for each `a` and `b` is calculating in different process and then they are adding together in process 1. Is this right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How we can be sure we are calculating a and b in a different process?

You can't unless you use `@spawnat n` and ensure that `nprocs()` is greater than or equal to `n`, and that the `n`s are different.

> Is this right?

Yes, assuming that you've used `@spawnat 1` for `a`. You can test this by rewriting your function as follows:

```
julia> @everywhere function count_hands(n)
           println("this process is $(myid())")
           c::Int=0
           for i=1:n
               c+=rand(Bool)
           end
           c
       end

julia> a = @spawnat 1 count_hands(1000)
this process is 1
Future(1, 1, 11, Nullable{Any}())

julia> b = @spawnat 2 count_hands(1000)
Future(2, 1, 12, Nullable{Any}())

julia>  From worker 2:  this process is 2
julia>

julia> fetch(a) + fetch(b)
1021
```